# Return the last k numbers of a list (Python)

Tags: list, function

I need to return the last k numbers of a list in Python without importing any new libraries

list1=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

def example(list1,k)

return ???

I need to return the last (k)  numbers of list1.
For example if (k) is 2 then the function will return [6,7]
Another example if (k) is 4 then it returns [4,5,6,7]

do you have any advice to accomplish this?
thanks

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-get-last-n-elements-from-given-list/

Comment: Try `list1[-k:]`?